# C++ datetime parse

Tags: c++, datetime

I use `strptime` to parse datetime string into `tm` structure.
But I faced a problem:

I have date in this format:

```
Thu Dec 13 23:44:45 MSK 2012
```

I parse `Thu Dec 13 23:44:45` with `"%a %b %d %T"` format string.
But I can't understand how to parse year. I can't just use `"%a %b %d %T MSK %Y"` because I want locale-independent parser.

Can I just skip `MSK` word? Or any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: @Just_Mad It appears that %Z only works in [glibc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strptime.3.html)

Comment: @Just_Mad it seeems to be right, but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find an answer, so I wrote my own datetime parser:

```
time_t timeParse(const char *string, struct tm *datetime)
{
    char dn[4], mn[4], ln[4];
    int d, h, m, s, y;
    sscanf(string, "%s %s %d %d:%d:%d %s %d", dn, mn, &d, &h, &m, &s, ln, &y);
    datetime->tm_sec = s;
    datetime->tm_min = m;
    datetime->tm_hour = h;
    datetime->tm_mday = d;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Jan")) datetime->tm_mon = 0;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Feb")) datetime->tm_mon = 1;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Mar")) datetime->tm_mon = 2;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Apr")) datetime->tm_mon = 3;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "May")) datetime->tm_mon = 4;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Jun")) datetime->tm_mon = 5;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Jul")) datetime->tm_mon = 6;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Aug")) datetime->tm_mon = 7;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Sep")) datetime->tm_mon = 8;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Oct")) datetime->tm_mon = 9;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Nov")) datetime->tm_mon = 10;
    if (!strcmp(mn, "Dec")) datetime->tm_mon = 11;
    datetime->tm_year = y - 1900;
    return mktime(datetime);
}
```

I fill necessary `tm structure` fields manually and `mktime` fills remaining fields: `tm_wday`, `tm_yday`, `tm_isdst`.

You should call it this way:

```
time_t t = timeParse("Thu Dec 13 23:44:45 MSK 2012", &datetime);
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `sscanf`, and also specify width for the char arrays in the `sscanf` format string. If you do not, that function is a subtle memory corruption bug waiting to happen (or, worse, a security hole waiting for exploitation). A paranoid coder would also pre-initialize the char arrays to `{0}`, it's always safest to keep strings null-terminated in case there's unexpected code execution flow.

Comment: Why is it necessary to pass structure "datetime" to this function? You fill all structure fields inside your function, why it can't be created and destroyed inside it?

Comment: @Just_Mad I need to have both time_t and struct tm representations of time.